# Can you safely delete folders in AppData?

Tags: windows-10

Is the folder located at C:\Users%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts...  cache for files on my NAS, and as such can I safely delete this folder without losing the files on the NAS? This is now 40 GB on a 128GB SSD...

Comment: Just a note that AppData contains per-user app artifacts like configuration or data files. As such many are safe to delete, whereas many will contain information you want to keep (like game savefiles). you are doing the right thing by investigating the specific thing you want to delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly safe.  This is just a local cached copy.  It will not affect your NAS.

Comment: As a curious user who always wants to learn something I checked this directory and see no files present. What is the purpose of this file if it is present and why dont I have one

Comment: I'm guessing that this storage is for offline-files storage, but thats just a guess.